# Save emails to pdf without notification

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I have found this code to download emails and convert them to PDF. It works perfectly but the only question that I have is it possible to remove the save notification and that it saves it automaticly when you trigger the macro?
Below is whole my code:

```
Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing

Set MyOlNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set MySelectedItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'tmpFileName = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(2)
tmpFileName = "C:\CRM\Postboek\Ongekoppeld"
strRecieved = MySelectedItem.ReceivedByName
strSender = MySelectedItem.SenderName
strDatum = MySelectedItem.ReceivedTime
strDatum = Replace(strDatum, ":", "-")
strDatum = Replace(strDatum, "/", "-")
strName = "email_temp.mht"
tmpFileName = tmpFileName & "\" & strName
MySelectedItem.SaveAs tmpFileName, 10
On Error Resume Next
'           If MySelectedItem.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
 '               strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
 '           Else
 '               strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
 ''               strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
  '          End If
  '      If MySelectedItem.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
  '          MySelectedItem.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & MySelectedItem.Body
  '      Else
  '          MySelectedItem.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & MySelectedItem.HTMLBody
  '      End If
Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err Then
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
bStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=tmpFileName, Visible:=False, Format:=7)
Set dlgSaveAs = wrdApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
Set fdfs = dlgSaveAs.Filters
i = 0
For Each fdf In fdfs
i = i + 1
If InStr(1, fdf.Extensions, "pdf", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
Exit For
End If
Next fdf
dlgSaveAs.FilterIndex = i
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'SpecialPath = WshShell.SpecialFolders(16)
SpecialPath = "C:\CRM\Postboek\Ongekoppeld"
msgFileName = MySelectedItem.Subject
msgFileName = Replace(msgFileName, ":", "-")
Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
oRegEx.Global = True
oRegEx.Pattern = "[\/:*?""<>|]"
'msgFileName = Trim(oRegEx.Replace(msgFileName, ""))
'msgFileName = Trim(oRegEx.Replace(msgFileName, ""))
If Len(strRecieved) = 0 Then
    dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = SpecialPath & "\" & msgFileName & " - " & strSender & " - " & strDatum

ElseIf Len(strRecieved) > 0 Then
    dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = SpecialPath & "\" & msgFileName & " - " & strRecieved & " - " & strDatum
End If


'dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = SpecialPath & "\" & msgFileName & " - " & strRecieved & " - " & strDatum
If dlgSaveAs.Show = -1 Then
    strCurrentFile = dlgSaveAs.SelectedItems(1)
    If Right(strCurrentFile, 4) <> ".pdf" Then
        Response = MsgBox("Sorry, only saving in the pdf-format is supported." & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Save as pdf instead?", vbInformation + vbOKCancel)
        If Response = vbCancel Then
            wrdDoc.Close 0
            If bStarted Then wrdApp.Quit
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Response = vbOK Then
            intPos = InStrRev(strCurrentFile, ".")
                If intPos > 0 Then
                strCurrentFile = Left(strCurrentFile, intPos - 1)
                End If
        strCurrentFile = strCurrentFile & ".pdf"
    End If
End If
wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
strCurrentFile, _
ExportFormat:=17, _
OpenAfterExport:=False, _
OptimizeFor:=0, _
Range:=0, _
From:=0, _
To:=0, _
Item:=0, _
IncludeDocProps:=True, _
KeepIRM:=True, _
CreateBookmarks:=0, _
DocStructureTags:=True, _
BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
UseISO19005_1:=False
End If
Set dlgSaveAs = Nothing
wrdDoc.Close
If bStarted Then wrdApp.Quit
Set MyOlNamespace = Nothing
Set MySelectedItem = Nothing
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
Set wrdApp = Nothing
Set oRegEx = Nothing


End Sub
```

This part gives the notification to the user if they  want to save it and I actually just want it removed:

```
If dlgSaveAs.Show = -1 Then
    strCurrentFile = dlgSaveAs.SelectedItems(1)
    If Right(strCurrentFile, 4) <> ".pdf" Then
        Response = MsgBox("Sorry, only saving in the pdf-format is supported." & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Save as pdf instead?", vbInformation + vbOKCancel)
        If Response = vbCancel Then
            wrdDoc.Close 0
            If bStarted Then wrdApp.Quit
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Response = vbOK Then
            intPos = InStrRev(strCurrentFile, ".")
                If intPos > 0 Then
                strCurrentFile = Left(strCurrentFile, intPos - 1)
                End If
        strCurrentFile = strCurrentFile & ".pdf"
    End If
End If
```

Here is a screenshot of what I want to be removed:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MNuM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part:

```
If Len(strRecieved) = 0 Then
    dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = SpecialPath & "\" & msgFileName & " - " & strSender & " - " & strDatum

ElseIf Len(strRecieved) > 0 Then
    dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = SpecialPath & "\" & msgFileName & " - " & strRecieved & " - " & strDatum
End If


'dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = SpecialPath & "\" & msgFileName & " - " & strRecieved & " - " & strDatum
If dlgSaveAs.Show = -1 Then
    strCurrentFile = dlgSaveAs.SelectedItems(1)
    If Right(strCurrentFile, 4) <> ".pdf" Then
        Response = MsgBox("Sorry, only saving in the pdf-format is supported." & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Save as pdf instead?", vbInformation + vbOKCancel)
        If Response = vbCancel Then
            wrdDoc.Close 0
            If bStarted Then wrdApp.Quit
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Response = vbOK Then
            intPos = InStrRev(strCurrentFile, ".")
                If intPos > 0 Then
                strCurrentFile = Left(strCurrentFile, intPos - 1)
                End If
        strCurrentFile = strCurrentFile & ".pdf"
    End If
End If
```

Set the file name you want below:

```
wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
___PUTYOURFILENAMEHERE___, _
ExportFormat:=17, _
OpenAfterExport:=False, _
OptimizeFor:=0, _
Range:=0, _
From:=0, _
To:=0, _
Item:=0, _
IncludeDocProps:=True, _
KeepIRM:=True, _
CreateBookmarks:=0, _
DocStructureTags:=True, _
BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
UseISO19005_1:=False
```

Comment: I will still need this part:

Comment: If Len(strRecieved) = 0 Then
   ' dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = SpecialPath & "\" & msgFileName & " - " & strSender & " - " & strDatum'
    
'ElseIf Len(strRecieved) > 0 Then
'    dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = SpecialPath & "\" & msgFileName & " - " & strRecieved & " - " & strDatum
'End If

Comment: @MiranoDesigns you need to define your file name a bit differently. The entire piece I pointed out is based around dialog box you want to get rid of. Build your file name differently, while still checking `strReceived` and `strSender` variables. I now see you can remove even more of this code, you don't need `dlgSaveAs `, `fdfs` parts. You don't use regex either, as far as I can see.

Comment: In general, I suggest reverse approach. Instead of copying entire code from somebody else, and trying to figure out what to remove, copy only these lines that actually do what you want. So as far as I understand, you want code to save mail item, open it in word, and save as pdf with a given name.

Comment: What's regex and yes I want it to happen without the user to notice.

Comment: @MiranoDesigns I mean `oRegEx` object that employs regular expression to remove characters not allowed in file name. In your code you create this object, but do not use it. I strongly recommend figuring out what each line of your code does.

Comment: I know what each line of my code does, that not the issue. I just want it to save automaticly without a notification.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't look like that. I wrote what you need to remove, and that you need to define your file name in a different way. Currently it's dialog box that is responsible for your file name. You shouldn't expect your entire code be rewritten by somebody else.